# Surface area of a cone vs surface area of sphere using method of rings

Tags: calculus, area

Using the following figure of a hollow cone (without surface at the bottom) as reference:

[image]

I decided to calculate the surface area using the method of rings. One small ring has area $ 2\pi(l\sin\theta)dl $

$$ \int_0^L 2\pi(l\sin\theta)\, dl = 2\pi(\sin\theta) \int_0^L l\, dl = 2\pi(\sin\theta) \frac{L^2}{2} = \pi(\sin\theta) L^2 $$

As $ \sin\theta $ is  $ \frac{R}{L} $:

$$ \pi(\sin\theta) L^2 = \pi R L $$

Which is the right surface area for the cone.

However, I remember that for the surface area of a sphere we can't use this method (slicing the sphere in rings). So I was wondering why does this method work for a cone.

Comment: What would you call dl in a circle?

Comment: There is not really a correspondence to $l$ and $\theta$ for a sphere.  But you can do something similar integrating along a diameter, so long as you remember that the ring is sloping (which is an effect of your $\text{d}l$ term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly the same way. Let $l$ be the distance from the top of the sphere. Then, using $r$ the distance to the vertical axis,  you need to integrate $$\int_0^{\pi R} 2\pi r\ dl$$
So you need to find the relationship between $r$ and $l$. $$r=R\sin\theta=R\sin\frac lR$$
Then the area is $$\int_0^{\pi R}2\pi R\sin\frac lR dl=2\pi R^2\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta=4\pi R^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where does the upper limit of integration, $ \pi R $, comes from?

Comment: If you draw the similar image for the sphere, the distance from the top to the bottom is half of the circumference: $\frac{2\pi R}2=\pi R$